# Placing a negative index in C++

Tags: c++

In Python and C#, we need to place a negative index to get last value.

In C++, I don't know how to do it. I tried the same way to do it but it didn't work out.

**Example**

```cpp
string str = "get last space "
cout << str[-1];
```

In this example, I should get `null` value because there's a tailing space in the string. How can I do this?

Comment: Remember that for any string (or container in general) the valid range of indexes is `0` to `container.length() - 1` (inclusive). When you use `-1` as index, you get the character "before" the string, which is out of bounds and leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: First, in C++ you can't get last element of array/string/etc referring to -1st index. Use `str[str.length() - 1]` or `str.back()`. Second, you won't get null, you'll get space character.

Comment: And generally speaking you can't use constructs or expressions possible in other languages. They seldom (if ever) work, or at least not work the same way. Different language are different (much like spoken and written languages differ).

Comment: To find the length of a string, you can use [`std::string::length`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size). Therefore, to get the last character of a string, if you are sure that the length is at least one, you can write `str[str.length()-1]`.

Comment: Perhaps you need to spend some time to actually *learn* C++? Do you have [some decent books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read? Are you taking classes?

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << str[str.length() - 1];
```

`str.length()`will return the number of chars in this string, and to get the char at the end of str, you should use the index of the end char, which is 1 less than str length, since 0 is the first index

Answer (score 2):

you can use `back()` method in string class :

```
string str = "get last space ";
cout << str.back();
```

its return `char&` to last character in string

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `std::string`, you can use the method `std.back();`.

```cpp
cout << str.back();
```

This will get the last character of the string as you wish.

Comment: You can use `str.back();` instead of `str[str.size() - 1];`

Comment: Ok, Thomas Sablik. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one mentioned `str.back()` is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) if `str` is empty, I'd like to elaborate on it.

```cpp
std::cout << str.back(); // Trigger UB if str.emtpy() == true
```

The better form is as following:

```
if(str.empty() == false){
   std::cout << str.back();
}
```

Since `str.back()` is equivalent to `str[str.length()-1]`, they both have UB when `str` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `str.end()` iterator

```
string str = "get last space ";
cout << *(str.end()-1);
```